# find a field and move it to before the end of the line

Tags: sed

I have the following line and I want to find the field containing "ABCD" and move it just before the last field on the line.

```
string1;string2;xxxABCDxxx;string3;string4;string5;string6
```

Output

```
string1;string2;string3;string4;string5;xxxABCDxxx;string6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
sed 's/\([^;]*ABCD[^;]*;\)\(.*;\)/\2\1/' <in >out
```

That should probably do it.

It will only work for the *first* occurrence of an *`ABCD`* field, though. If there are more than one on the line, all of the rest will be skipped.

To swap the last `;` semicolon for a forward slash, just alter it a little:

```sh
sed 's|\([^;]*ABCD[^;]*\);\(.*;\)|\2\1/|' <in >out
```

Comment: thanks mike. it works perfect.  can you help me also to get this output  string1;string2;string3;string4;string5;xxxABCDxxx/string6

Comment: it works perfect.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that before but thank for telling me. I did pushed the buttons

Answer (score 3):

If you're not tied to sed:

```
awk -v pattern="ABCD" '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = ";" }
    {
        # find the first field containing the string
        for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i ~ pattern) break

        # alter the last field to the desired contents
        $NF = $i "/" $NF

        # shift each subsequent field one place
        for (;i<NF; i++) $i = $(i+1)

        # reset the number of fields
        NF--

        # and output the new line
        print
    }
' filename
```

Comment: Ok, this is cool. Most of the time the `awk` answers are not well explained *(from my perspective - I'm `awk` stupid)*. But this makes sense. Thanks.